# Does switching all contests to Roll vs Passive DC change the odds?

Tags: dnd-5e, house-rules, statistics

Does switching all contests from **Roll vs Roll** to **Roll vs Passive DC** change the odds?

**Example:** Player tries to grapple a medium opponent, let's say both the grappler and target have a Strength modifier of +0 and no Athletics or Acrobatics proficiency.

Usually one would have a contest: **Grappler 1d20+Bonus** vs **Target 1d20+Bonus**.

Does changing it to **Grappler 1d20+Bonus** vs **10+Bonus** affect the odds?

**If it changes the odds:**

- Are the odds affected by the Bonuses? How so?
- Is there a number, instead of 10, that one can use to preserve the odds of a standard contest?

*Note: Bonuses to either side, be it a static bonus or a die roll, would be handled normally and added to results*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## It generally favors the attacker, with exceptions

This isn't a terribly surprising result: the average outcome of 1d20 + bonus is literally equal to 10.5 + bonus, which is 0.5 points greater than 10 + bonus, resulting in a 2.5% point improvement in overall odds (assuming equal bonuses).

To verify, I wrote a quick program to calculate the odds of an attacker beating a defender, when they both have the same bonus, using active odds (both roll a d20) and passive odds (attacker rolls d20, defender takes 10). As expected, the odds for actively rolled dice are about 2.5% fewer for the attacker than the passively rolled dice:

```
//You'd naturally expect all the odds to be better than 50%, since the attacker wins ties
//Equal Bonuses:
Active Results:  5250737 out of 10000000 (52.507369999999995%)
Passive Results: 5498955 out of 10000000 (54.98955%)

//Repeated the trial several times to show accuracy: results are all within 0.04% of each other
Active Results:  5248819 out of 10000000 (52.48819%)
Passive Results: 5498203 out of 10000000 (54.98203%)

Active Results:  5249101 out of 10000000 (52.49101%)
Passive Results: 5500179 out of 10000000 (55.00178999999999%)

Active Results:  5249686 out of 10000000 (52.49686%)
Passive Results: 5501477 out of 10000000 (55.01477%)

Active Results:  5249980 out of 10000000 (52.49979999999999%)
Passive Results: 5499290 out of 10000000 (54.9929%)
```

The results speak for themselves.

## The Outcomes get very dramatic if one of the bonuses is much larger than the other, and high defender bonuses will cause the system to favor the defender

The 2.5% difference only holds when the bonuses are equal. When they're unequal, it will skew slightly above or slightly below 2.5% for small differences, and drastically alter the outcomes for big differences. The following stats represent the **difference** in ability scores for the attacker and defender respectively—in other words, "Attacker: 5, Defender: 0" means the Attacker's bonus is 5 points more than the Defender's bonus. Only the difference matters: If the Attacker has a bonus of +7, and the Defender has a bonus of +4, the stats are precisely identical to a scenario where the Attacker has +3 and the Defender has +0.

```
//Difference is 2.5%
Attacker: 0, Defender: 0
Active Results:  5249125 out of 10000000 (52.49125%)
Passive Results: 5499626 out of 10000000 (54.99626%)

//Note that Attacker:2, Defender:1 has identical odds/similar results
Attacker: 1, Defender: 0
Active Results:  5722711 out of 10000000 (57.22711%)
Passive Results: 6000753 out of 10000000 (60.007529999999996%)

//Attacker:3, Defender:1; Attacker:4, Defender:2, etc.
Attacker: 2, Defender: 0
Active Results:  6174039 out of 10000000 (61.74039%)
Passive Results: 6499936 out of 10000000 (64.99936%)

Attacker: 3, Defender: 0
Active Results:  6601101 out of 10000000 (66.01101%)
Passive Results: 7000450 out of 10000000 (70.00450000000001%)

//Difference is 5%, passive is like the attacker has a +1.2 + bonus in active
Attacker: 4, Defender: 0
Active Results:  7000297 out of 10000000 (70.00297%)
Passive Results: 7497731 out of 10000000 (74.97731%)

Attacker: 5, Defender: 0
Active Results:  7375115 out of 10000000 (73.75115%)
Passive Results: 8000631 out of 10000000 (80.00631%)

//Effective attacker bonus is 2 + bonus
Attacker: 6, Defender: 0
Active Results:  7726113 out of 10000000 (77.26113%)
Passive Results: 8501084 out of 10000000 (85.01084%)

//+4
Attacker: 7, Defender: 0
Active Results:  8051381 out of 10000000 (80.51380999999999%)
Passive Results: 8999331 out of 10000000 (89.99331000000001%)

//+5
Attacker: 8, Defender: 0
Active Results:  8350069 out of 10000000 (83.50069%)
Passive Results: 9500553 out of 10000000 (95.00553000000001%)

//Attacker wins ***every roll***, as opposed to winning 86% of rolls
//Is effectively 10 + bonus
Attacker: 9, Defender: 0
Active Results:  8626220 out of 10000000 (86.2622%)
Passive Results: 10000000 out of 10000000 (100.0%)

Attacker: 10, Defender: 0
Active Results:  8875606 out of 10000000 (88.75606%)
Passive Results: 10000000 out of 10000000 (100.0%)

Attacker: 11, Defender: 0
Active Results:  9099772 out of 10000000 (90.99772%)
Passive Results: 10000000 out of 10000000 (100.0%)

Attacker: 12, Defender: 0
Active Results:  9300587 out of 10000000 (93.00587%)
Passive Results: 10000000 out of 10000000 (100.0%)

Attacker: 13, Defender: 0
Active Results:  9474565 out of 10000000 (94.74565%)
Passive Results: 10000000 out of 10000000 (100.0%)

Attacker: 14, Defender: 0
Active Results:  9625309 out of 10000000 (96.25309%)
Passive Results: 10000000 out of 10000000 (100.0%)

Attacker: 15, Defender: 0
Active Results:  9749404 out of 10000000 (97.49404%)
Passive Results: 10000000 out of 10000000 (100.0%)

Attacker: 16, Defender: 0
Active Results:  9850722 out of 10000000 (98.50721999999999%)
Passive Results: 10000000 out of 10000000 (100.0%)

Attacker: 17, Defender: 0
Active Results:  9925287 out of 10000000 (99.25287%)
Passive Results: 10000000 out of 10000000 (100.0%)

Attacker: 18, Defender: 0
Active Results:  9974967 out of 10000000 (99.74967%)
Passive Results: 10000000 out of 10000000 (100.0%)

Attacker: 19, Defender: 0
Active Results:  10000000 out of 10000000 (100.0%)
Passive Results: 10000000 out of 10000000 (100.0%)

Attacker: 20, Defender: 0
Active Results:  10000000 out of 10000000 (100.0%)
Passive Results: 10000000 out of 10000000 (100.0%)

//Now we consider situations where defender has a better bonus
Attacker: 0, Defender: 1
Active Results:  4750868 out of 10000000 (47.50868%)
Passive Results: 4998554 out of 10000000 (49.98554%)

Attacker: 0, Defender: 2
Active Results:  4277085 out of 10000000 (42.770849999999996%)
Passive Results: 4498389 out of 10000000 (44.983889999999995%)

Attacker: 0, Defender: 3
Active Results:  3824786 out of 10000000 (38.24786%)
Passive Results: 4002931 out of 10000000 (40.02931%)

Attacker: 0, Defender: 4
Active Results:  3399840 out of 10000000 (33.998400000000004%)
Passive Results: 3500342 out of 10000000 (35.00342%)

//Curiously, passive starts to harm attacker in this situation
Attacker: 0, Defender: 5
Active Results:  2999828 out of 10000000 (29.99828%)
Passive Results: 2996882 out of 10000000 (29.96882%)

//Effectively attacker -1
Attacker: 0, Defender: 6
Active Results:  2626743 out of 10000000 (26.267430000000004%)
Passive Results: 2499426 out of 10000000 (24.994259999999997%)

Attacker: 0, Defender: 7
Active Results:  2275216 out of 10000000 (22.75216%)
Passive Results: 2001180 out of 10000000 (20.011799999999997%)

//Effectively attacker -2
Attacker: 0, Defender: 8
Active Results:  1949354 out of 10000000 (19.49354%)
Passive Results: 1498727 out of 10000000 (14.98727%)

//-3
Attacker: 0, Defender: 9
Active Results:  1650522 out of 10000000 (16.50522%)
Passive Results: 999070 out of 10000000 (9.9907%)

//-4
Attacker: 0, Defender: 10
Active Results:  1375942 out of 10000000 (13.75942%)
Passive Results: 500388 out of 10000000 (5.0038800000000005%)

//Attacker cannot win rolls
//Effectively -9
Attacker: 0, Defender: 11
Active Results:  1125553 out of 10000000 (11.25553%)
Passive Results: 0 out of 10000000 (0.0%)

Attacker: 0, Defender: 12
Active Results:  899999 out of 10000000 (8.999989999999999%)
Passive Results: 0 out of 10000000 (0.0%)

Attacker: 0, Defender: 13
Active Results:  700584 out of 10000000 (7.005840000000001%)
Passive Results: 0 out of 10000000 (0.0%)

Attacker: 0, Defender: 14
Active Results:  525539 out of 10000000 (5.25539%)
Passive Results: 0 out of 10000000 (0.0%)

Attacker: 0, Defender: 15
Active Results:  375152 out of 10000000 (3.7515199999999997%)
Passive Results: 0 out of 10000000 (0.0%)

Attacker: 0, Defender: 16
Active Results:  250269 out of 10000000 (2.5026900000000003%)
Passive Results: 0 out of 10000000 (0.0%)

Attacker: 0, Defender: 17
Active Results:  149511 out of 10000000 (1.49511%)
Passive Results: 0 out of 10000000 (0.0%)

Attacker: 0, Defender: 18
Active Results:  74403 out of 10000000 (0.7440300000000001%)
Passive Results: 0 out of 10000000 (0.0%)

Attacker: 0, Defender: 19
Active Results:  25251 out of 10000000 (0.25251%)
Passive Results: 0 out of 10000000 (0.0%)

Attacker: 0, Defender: 20
Active Results:  0 out of 10000000 (0.0%)
Passive Results: 0 out of 10000000 (0.0%)
```

To summarize for people who have difficulty reading a lot of stats, if OP's ruleset is referred to as Passive, and 5e-default is Active, then:

- In the range Defender+4 to Attacker+3, Passive yields a +2.5% bonus
- At Passive-Attacker+4, equivalent is Active-Attacker+5
- At Passive-Attacker+6, equivalent is Active-Attacker+8
- At Passive-Attacker+9, Attacker wins every roll, always, is equivalent to Active-Attacker+19
- At Passive-Defender+5, equivalent is Active-Defender+5
- At Passive-Defender+6, equivalent is Active-Defender+7
- At Passive-Defender+11, the Defender wins every roll, always, is equivalent to Active-Defender+20

The good news is, bonus discrepancies like I showed are pretty rare: unless your party is fighting a creature way outside their effective CR, bonus differences greater than 8 really shouldn't ever happen.

The bad news is, a lot of this stuff goes against the 5e policy of ensuring Bounded Accuracy: by creating scenarios where an opponent can literally win every single ability roll against an opponent, beyond a certain differential in ability. Furthermore, Expertise is an easy way to boost a score into the +9 range, which would make this system dangerous and easy to exploit for any creature with expertise in a skill.

## Example of how this would play in practice

You are a level 5 Bard, with expertise in Deception. You've been caught by the king in bed with his son, and need to explain yourself. Now let's give the king some credit: he's not a total idiot. He's probably got a Wisdom score of 12, giving him a +1 to Insight checks.

But there's a problem, for him at least: You, the charming bard, have a +10 to your Deception check. Now, normally, you'd probably have to roll with disadvantage, because you're in a compromising situation: even with all your bonuses, you'd still need some luck to evade consequences. In the normal 5e system, you'd have an 86% chance of passing any given roll, and with disadvantage, your odds of passing are (0.86)^2, which is 74%, about 3/4. That's pretty reasonable, given your ability to lie your pants off (in this case, apparently literally).

But in the system OP suggests, it doesn't really matter: at +1, the bonus the king receives is automatically 11. With a bonus of +10, the *lowest possible roll you can make is 11*, which beats the king's insight score (remember that ability checks don't have critical failures). Even if the king is much smarter (Insight +4), you've still improved a 65% chance of success to a 81% chance of success, going from 2/3 to 4/5.

And this generally applies to any Rogue/Bard with expertise in a skill for their favored ability score: unless the creatures they face are artificially buffed beyond what their CR would normally allow, they'll be able to walk all over anyone with any ability check using their scores.

## I probably wouldn't implement this system

It's relatively harmless at lower level/lower differences in bonuses, but it violates a core design principle of 5e in more drastic scenarios, and could upset the overall balance of creatures that have unusually high bonuses for one or more ability score.

#### Code, for reference (written in Java):

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;

public class ProbabilityTesting {
    public static class Pair<K,V> implements Cloneable{
        public final K first;
        public final V second;
        public Pair() {
            this(null, null);
        }
        
        public Pair(K first, V second) {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }
        
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if(this == o) return true;
            if(!(o instanceof Pair<?,?>)) {
                return false;
            }
            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Pair<K,V> p = (Pair<K,V>)o;
                return Objects.equals(first, p.first) && Objects.equals(second, p.second);
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        @Override
        public Object clone() {
            return new Pair<>(first, second);
        }
        
        public static<K,V> Pair<K, V> of(K k, V v) {
            return new Pair<>(k, v);
        }
    }
    private static class Calculator {
        private boolean use_passive;
        private int attacker_bonus;
        private int defender_bonus;
        private int num_of_trials;
        
        public Calculator(boolean use_passive, int attacker_bonus, int defender_bonus, int num_of_trials) {
            this.use_passive = use_passive;
            this.attacker_bonus = attacker_bonus;
            this.defender_bonus = defender_bonus;
            this.num_of_trials = num_of_trials;
        }
        
        public Pair<Integer, Integer> call() throws Exception {
            int successes = 0;
            Random rand = new Random();
            for(int i = 0; i < num_of_trials; i++) {
                int attacker_score = rand.nextInt(20) + 1 + attacker_bonus;
                int defender_score;
                if(use_passive)
                    defender_score = 10 + defender_bonus;
                else
                    defender_score = rand.nextInt(20) + 1 + defender_bonus;
                //Attacker wins ties
                if(attacker_score >= defender_score) 
                    successes++;
            }
            return Pair.of(successes, num_of_trials);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for(int i = 0; i < 41; i++) {
            int attacker_bonus, defender_bonus;
            if(i < 21) {
                attacker_bonus = i;
                defender_bonus = 0;
            } else {
                attacker_bonus = 0;
                defender_bonus = i - 20;
            }
            Calculator active = new Calculator(false, attacker_bonus, defender_bonus, 10_000_000);
            Calculator passive = new Calculator(true, attacker_bonus, defender_bonus, 10_000_000);
            
            Pair<Integer, Integer> active_results = active.call(), passive_results = passive.call();
            System.out.println("Attacker: " + attacker_bonus + ", Defender: " + defender_bonus);
            System.out.println("Active Results:  " + active_results.first + " out of " + active_results.second + " (" + (active_results.first / (double)active_results.second * 100) + "%)");
            System.out.println("Passive Results: " + passive_results.first + " out of " + passive_results.second + " (" + (passive_results.first / (double)passive_results.second * 100) + "%)");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion. If you intend to comment on a sticking point you see in this presentation--and it looks like people doing so have helped OP fortify this post-- please go ahead and converse in [chat on this post](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79248/discussion-on-answer-by-xirema-does-switching-all-contests-to-roll-vs-passive-dc).

Comment: For your scenario with the kings son wouldn't the disadvantage likely be represented by the standard -5 putting it well within contest territory?